# Why replace() is not working for '$' symbol?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all the '$' in a string, I am using simple `replace()` function. It is working for other substring but not for '$' symbol. Any reason why?

```js
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/,/g , ":"));

var mystring2 = "this$is$a$test"
console.log(mystring2.replace(/$/g , ":"));
```

Comment: Please comment if you down vote the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$` has special meaning in a regular expression, it matches the end of the string. You need to escape it to use it literally.

```js
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/,/g , ":"));

var mystring2 = "this$is$a$test"
console.log(mystring2.replace(/\$/g , ":"));
```

You should read an regular expression tutorial, like the one at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 4):

Because $ is a special identifier in regular expressions and should be escaped

```
var mystring2 = "this$is$a$test"
console.log(mystring2.replace(/\$/g , ":"));
```